# how can i modify scale labels in angular chart js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart, chart.js

I'm trying to add my own scale labels in `angular chart js` like in this issue https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/33, the problem is that when I try that example, even with the same code it doesn't work, it won't take the options I assign in my scope.

Since I have 4 states that will be the same, I was thinking I could make a function like this, but I'm having trouble even adding a simple option.

This is my controller code:

```
$scope.options = {
    scaleLabel  : function (label) {

        if(Number(label)===1)    
            return 'State 1';
        if(Number(label.value)===2)    
            return 'State 2';
        if(Number(label.value)===3)    
            return 'State 3';
        if(Number(label.value)===4)    
            return 'State 4';
    } 
};

$scope.series = ['Table 1']; 
$scope.axis = [[1,2,3,3,4,2,1,2,3,4]];
$scope.myLabels= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

This is my markup:

```
<br>
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="axis"
    chart-labels="myLabels" chart-series="series"  chart-options="options"
</canvas>
```

Comment: Post the series configuration

Comment: @Sajeetharan done, did they change scaleLabel? im testing various example in the chart.js, when i added a predefined scale label it shows.

Comment: what about the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to put your own labels in the 'y' axis you have to use the tick options, scale label will only modify the label of the axis of the whole, so let's say you want to add a label for your y axis, like 3000$ instead of only 3000.

you need to use this.

```
 ticks: {
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
 //your function here
     }
}
```

in this example i wanted to return 3 states for each value, like a ticket system.

```
    $scope.options = {
   scales: {
            yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel:  {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Estado'
      },
      ticks: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 3,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {

                    if(value == 1){
var dasLabel='Ticket open';                             
                    }
                    if(value == 2){
var dasLabel='Attending ticket';                            
                    }
                    if(value == 3){
var dasLabel='issued resolved';                             
                    }       

                        return dasLabel;
                    }
                }
            }]  ,
            xAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Hora'
      }
            }]
        }
  };
```

and your markup

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="axis"
chart-labels="myLabels" chart-series="series"  chart-options="options"
</canvas>
```